# Vuetify: Reduce brightness of image but not of the text

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I am currently coding a card element with a background image and a centered text. Currently it looks like this:

```
<template>
  <v-card
    class="tile"
    @mouseenter="isHovered = true"
    @mouseleave="isHovered = false"
  >
    <v-img
      src="https://picsum.photos/800/800"
      aspect-ratio="2.5"
      :style="imageStyle"
    >
      <template v-slot:placeholder>
        <div class="d-flex align-center justify-center fill-height">
          <v-progress-circular
            color="grey-lighten-4"
            indeterminate
          ></v-progress-circular>
        </div>
      </template>
      <v-card-text class="tile-content">
        <div class="text-center">
          <div class="headline" v-text="title"></div>
          <div class="descriptionContainer" :class="{ show: isHovered }">
            <div v-text="description" class="description"></div>
            <v-btn :href="link" color="transparent" class="white-border" text>
              {{ buttonText }}
            </v-btn>
          </div>
        </div>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-img>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    title: String,
    description: String,
    imagePath: String,
    link: String,
    buttonText: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isHovered: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {},
  computed: {
    imageStyle() {
      return {
        filter: this.isHovered ? "brightness(60%)" : "none",
      };
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I had to place the `<v-card-text>`-Tag inside of the image to center it. What I want to do now is the following: As soon as the user hovers over the `<v-card>` the image brightness shall be reduced. This is working perfectly but unfortunately the title, description and button are also affected by this. So the problem is that the user cant read it anymore .... Is there a way to reduce the brightness of the image without affecting the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply the brightness filter directly to the actual `img` element, instead of `v-img` using [Vue 3 deep selector](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#deep-selectors)

```css
<style scoped>
  .v-img:hover :deep(img) {
    filter: brightness(60%);
  }
</style>
```

and then remove `:style="imageStyle"` from `v-img`

[Vuetify Playground example](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use position: fixed for that, below is a example, where v-card is a reference container for both image and overlay over image which contains text and button

[Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Code

```js
<template>
  <v-card
    class="tile"
    @mouseenter="isHovered = true"
    @mouseleave="isHovered = false"
  >
    <v-img
      src="https://picsum.photos/800/800"
      aspect-ratio="2.5"
      :style="imageStyle"
    >
      <template v-slot:placeholder>
        <div class="d-flex align-center justify-center fill-height">
          <v-progress-circular
            color="grey-lighten-4"
            indeterminate
          ></v-progress-circular>
        </div>
      </template>
    </v-img>
    <v-card class="tile-content test" position="absolute">
      Fixed overlay over the image

      <div class="text-center">
        <div class="headline" v-text="title"></div>
        <div class="descriptionContainer" :class="{ show: isHovered }">
          <div v-text="description" class="description"></div>
          <v-btn :href="link" color="transparent" class="white-border" text>
            Button
          </v-btn>
        </div>
      </div>
    </v-card>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      title: String,
      description: String,
      imagePath: String,
      link: String,
      buttonText: String,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        isHovered: false,
      }
    },
    methods: {},
    computed: {
      imageStyle() {
        return {
          filter: this.isHovered ? 'brightness(60%)' : 'none',
        }
      },
    },
  }
</script>
<style>
  .test {
    top: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
</style>
```